# Proper way to create superclass from subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, client-server

I have an client-server application.

The client has a class: Item.java

```
public class Item
    public string name;
    public string size;
```

and the server has a class PersistableItem.java which lets me store it using JPA

```
public class PersistableItem extends Item
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long Id;
```

and sends it to the server which executes the addItemToServer method:

```
public void addItem( Item item){
    //create PersistableItem from item
    DAO.save([paramerter = PersistableItem]);     
}
```

In my server method do I cast the item as PersistableItem? Do i make a constructor in PersistableItem that takes in a Item?

What's the proper design here?

Comment: Let's count how many different classes you refer to in your text: `SomeItem` (1), `SomePersistableItem` (2), `PersistableItem` (3), and `PersistableSomeItem` (4). Of which, you show the relationship of precisely two of them: `SomePersistableItem` extends `SomeItem`. The more effort you put into making your question clear and correct, the more likely you are to receive useful answers.

Comment: Oh come on, it's clearly some typos, it doesn't hurt the understanding. The point is there is a base class, and a subclass made to make it persistable.

Comment: Precision is everything. For one, compilers are not very forgiving, for another, his question is a bit above rudimentary Java, for another, you yourself in another comment state that his question is not "crystal clear". If he really needs our free help, I would expect him to put in the effort to make his question as clear and as precise as possible, wouldn't you?

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't want to be too generic and call it 'Item' but I wanted to simplify my actual code (the actual base class has about 20 properties and 3 constructors and the super class another 6 but it's not all relevant to the core question) for easier understand but I got too fancy and made some typos. Thanks for backing me Guillaume, mistakes accounted for, I don't think it was too hard to read between the lines but I cleaned it up anyways.

Comment: I'm all for clarity and precision, and I'd agree with what you said Hovercraft, as a good principle, specially when asking for people's help - I'm just saying in that particular case, I could still understand the point even if not crystal clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suggested, You can create a constructor in SomePersistedItem that takes a SomeItem. In the constructor, you call super with the name and size, so you have your SomePersistedItem correctly populated.

```
public class SomePersistableItem extends SomeItem
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long Id;

    public SomePersistableItem(SomeItem originalItem) {
        super(originalItem.getName(), originalItem.getSize());
    }
```

And you just add it.

```
public void addItem( someItem item){
    DAO.save(new PersistableItem(item));     
}
```

That's assuming you have a constructor in SomeItem that takes a name and size. Else you use whatever method you have to build SomeItem (Factory, setters...)

Comment: Ok, that's what I'm doing now. I haven't messed around with a scenario like this in awhile but it seemed to me like there should be a way to create a superclass from a base class and then just populate the additional superclass properties, I guess not. Thanks!

Comment: Well, there is no "magic way", everything is about calling creators, and/or calling methods to populate values. What I shown is the simplest way to create a superclass from a base class.

Answer (score 0):

I would make your persistable item extend an interface

```
public interface Persistable {
    boolean persist();
}

public class SomePersistableItem extends SomeItem implements Persistable {

}

public void addItem(Persistable p) {
    p.persist();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't tell him how to turn his SomeItem into a Persistable, which I think is the original question. It's not crystal clear, but it's how I understand it